# How do I create a WPF DataGrid Text + Button Column?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, wpfdatagrid

I want a column in my datagrid to display both text and a small ellipsis "..." button - similar to what you see in the Visual Studio property grid. Here is a mockup of the datagrid column I'm trying to build:

[image: Mockup]

When the user clicks the ellipsis button, I will display a custom picker dialog and then in the text section of the column, display what I can of the comma sepatated values (i.e. string) returned from the dialog.

How do I get a datagrid column to contain both text and button as I have mocked up here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="mDataTemplate">
                <Button Margin="10,10,0,0" >
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">                                
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                                    
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock  />
                            <Ellipse />                                
                        </Grid>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources> </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Sample code:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Your header">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DockPanel>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right">...</Button>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourProperty}"></TextBlock>
          </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```